# Jquery Application that is similar to GMail's Web Phone App that is compatible with SIP

Tags: jquery, web-applications, browser, sip, voip

I'm looking for a plugin that is similar to GMails Phone apps but the app should be compatible with an SIP account, the app will be placed on a Website and the user will just simply login their usernames and password to be able to use the dialer is there any similar web base apps that can achieve this function, I've looked for some but the problem is the apps are not compatible with SIP and there are apps that must be installed directly to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Phono](http://phono.com/)?

The downside is that calls using the plugin will go through Tropo's (tropo.com, the company that sponsors the plugin) servers. The upside is it's very easy to get up and running.

**Update:**

You could also look at WebRTC options such as [sipML5](http://sipml5.org/call.htm). With WebRTC you should be able to configure things so that the media will be directly between the call end points thus alleviating some security concerns. Although if you have NATs anywhere in your call paths they will cause big headaches.

Comment: yes i've seen that and was considering the problem is that, the API will only allow 10 mins of call time and the conversations is not secure as they are taking sample conversation for future devs.